# PHP page stops loading during MySQL INSERT

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this function:

```
function addSteamProduct($id, $type = "app"){
  global $connection;
  $result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT 1 FROM products WHERE sid = '".$id."' AND ".($type == "app" ? "(p_type = 'game' OR p_type = 'dlc')" : "p_type = 'bundle'").";");
  $data = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  if($data != null)
    return "001";
  if($type == "app"){
    $json = file_get_contents("http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails/?cc=it&l=english&appids=".$id);
    $json = str_replace(array("<h1>", "<h2>", '<h1 class=\"bb_tag\">', '<h2 class=\"bb_tag\">'), '<div style=\"font-weight:bold\">', $json);
    $json = str_replace(array("<\/h1>", "<\/h2>"), "<\/div>", $json);
    $json = str_replace(array("<p>", "<\/p>"), array("<div>", "<\/div>"), $json);
  }
  else if($type == "sub")
    $json = file_get_contents("http://store.steampowered.com/api/packagedetails/?cc=it&l=english&packageids=".$id);
  $json = str_replace(array("\u00ae", "\u2122", "http:\/\/steamcommunity.com\/linkfilter\/?url=", "https:\/\/steamcommunity.com\/linkfilter\/?url="), "", $json);
  $json = json_decode($json, true);
  if(!$json[$id]["success"])
    return "001";
  else{
    $json = $json[$id]["data"];
    if(!in_array($json["type"], array("game", "dlc")) && $type != "sub")
      return "001";
    if(sizeof($json["price_overview"]) <= 0 && sizeof($json["price"]) <= 0)
      return "001";
    if($type == "sub"){
      for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($json["apps"]); $i++){
        $ids .= ($i == 0 ? "" : ",").$json["apps"][$i]["id"];
      }
      $json2 = file_get_contents("http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails/?cc=it&l=english&appids=".$ids);
      $json2 = str_replace(array("\u00ae", "\u2122", "http:\/\/steamcommunity.com\/linkfilter\/?url=", "https:\/\/steamcommunity.com\/linkfilter\/?url="), "", $json2);
      $json2 = json_decode($json2, true);
      while($json2[key($json2)]){
        for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($json2[key($json2)]["data"]["categories"]); $i++){
          if(!arrayKeySearch("id", $json2[key($json2)]["data"]["categories"][$i]["id"], $json["categories"]))
            $json["categories"][] = $json2[key($json2)]["data"]["categories"][$i];
        }
        for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($json2[key($json2)]["data"]["genres"]); $i++){
          if(!arrayKeySearch("id", $json2[key($json2)]["data"]["genres"][$i]["id"], $json["genres"]))
            $json["genres"][] = $json2[key($json2)]["data"]["genres"][$i];
        }
        next($json2);
      }
      reset($json2);
      $json["developers"] = $json2[key($json2)]["data"]["developers"];
      $json["publishers"] = $json2[key($json2)]["data"]["publishers"];
      $json["supported_languages"] = $json2[key($json2)]["data"]["supported_languages"];
      $json["screenshots"] = $json2[key($json2)]["data"]["screenshots"];
    }
    $data = array();
    $data["p_type"] = ($type == "app" ? ($json["type"] == "game" ? "game" : "dlc") : "bundle");
    $data["author_id"] = (sizeof($json["developers"]) > 0 ? implode(", ", $json["developers"]) : "NULL");
    $data["name"] = $json["name"];
    $data["parents_id"] = ($json["type"] == "dlc" ? $json["fullgame"]["appid"] : "NULL");
    $data["date_r"] = ($json["release_date"]["coming_soon"] == "true" ? "NRY" : ($json["release_date"]["date"] != "" ? strtotime($json["release_date"]["date"]) : "NULL"));
    $data["composers"] = (sizeof($json["publishers"]) > 0 ? implode(", ", $json["publishers"]) : "NULL");
    $data["description"] = ($type == "app" ? $json["detailed_description"] : "NULL");
    $data["inv_description"] = ($type == "app" ? $json["about_the_game"] : "NULL");
    $data["price"] = (sizeof($json["price_overview"]) > 0 ? preg_replace("/([0-9]{2})$/", ".$1", $json["price_overview"]["initial"]) : preg_replace("/([0-9]{2})$/", ".$1", $json["price"]["initial"]));
    $data["price_n"] = $data["price"];
    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($json["genres"]); $i++){
      $gen .= ($json["genres"][$i]["description"] != "Free to Play" ? ($gen == null ? "" : ",").$json["genres"][$i]["id"] : "");
    }
    $data["categories"] = $gen;
    $data["website"] = ($json["website"] != null ? rtrim($json["website"], "/") : "NULL");
    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($json["categories"]); $i++){
      $fea .= ($i == 0 ? "" : ",").$json["categories"][$i]["id"];
    }
    $data["features"] = $fea;
    $data["platforms"] = ($json["platforms"]["windows"] ? "w*" : "").($json["platforms"]["mac"] ? "m*" : "").($json["platforms"]["linux"] ? "l*" : "");
    $data["meta"] = ($type == "app" ? $json["metacritic"]["score"] : "NULL");
    $data["meta_url"] = ($type == "app" ? $json["metacritic"]["url"] : "NULL");
    if(sizeof($json["achievements"]["highlighted"]) > 0){
      for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($json["achievements"]["highlighted"]); $i++){
        $ach .= ($i == 0 ? "" : "\\\\").$json["achievements"]["highlighted"][$i]["name"]."=".$json["achievements"]["highlighted"][$i]["path"];
      }
    }
    $data["achievements"] = (sizeof($json["achievements"]["highlighted"]) > 0 ? $json["achievements"]["total"]."\\\\\\\\".$ach : "NULL");
    $data["lang"] = ($json["supported_languages"] != null ? str_replace("<br>", '<br><span style="font-style:italic">', $json["supported_languages"])."</span>" : "NULL");
    $data["sid"] = $id;
    if($type == "sub"){
      $ids_a = explode(",", $ids);
      for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($ids_a); $i++){
        addSteamProduct($ids_a[$i]);
      }
    }
    if($type == "app" && sizeof($json["dlc"]) > 0){
      for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($json["dlc"]); $i++){
        addSteamProduct($json["dlc"][$i]);
      }
    }
    $data["childs_id"] = ($type == "app" ? (sizeof($json["dlc"]) > 0 ? implode(",", $json["dlc"]) : "NULL") : $ids);
    foreach($data as &$value) {
      $value = str_replace("'", "\'", $value);
      $value = ($value != "NULL" ? "'".$value."'" : $value);
    }
    if(!$result = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO products (`".implode("`, `", array_keys($data))."`) VALUES (".implode(", ", array_values($data)).");"))
      return "001";
    $id2 = mysqli_insert_id($connection);
    if($type == "sub"){
      $result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT SUM(price) AS price_i FROM products WHERE sid IN(".$ids.") AND (p_type = 'game' OR p_type = 'dlc');");
      $data2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
      $result = mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE products SET price_i = '".$data2["price_i"]."' WHERE id = '".$id2."' AND p_type = 'bundle';");
      $result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name SEPARATOR ', ') AS names FROM products WHERE sid IN(".$ids.") AND (p_type = 'game' OR p_type = 'dlc');");
      $data2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
      $result = mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE products SET inv_description = 'A Steam bundle including the following games: ".$data2["names"]."' WHERE id = '".$id2."' AND p_type = 'bundle';");
    }
    if(getimagesize($json["header_image"]) === false){
      resizeImage($json["page_image"], 0, 136, "content/images/products/".$id2.".png", true);
      cutImage("http://www.xriuk.com/content/images/products/".$id2.".png", 292, 136, "content/images/products/".$id2.".png");
    }
    else
      resizeImage($json["header_image"], 292, 136, "content/images/products/".$id2.".png", true);
    $rand = rand(0, sizeof($json["screenshots"]) - 1);
    createBackground($json["screenshots"][$rand]["path_full"], "content/images/products_backgrounds/".$id2.".png");
    return $id2;
  }
}
```

Basically I run this `addSteamProduct(32848, "sub");`, the script gets a JSON from`http://store.steampowered.com/api/packagedetails/?cc=it&l=english&packageids=32848`, then does all stuff. The JSON of the package(32848) have an array of included apps, some of these apps may have an array of dlcs, I need to parse all this, so I follow this path:

```
- Get package info + apps list
- Check if every app already exists in DB, if it does, quit
- Get app info + DLCs list
- Get every DLC info and add to DB if not already exists
- Add app info to DB
- Repeat for every app
- Add package info to DB
```

This seems not to work, I have removed all PHP and MySQL time limit, but the page stops loading and the request is half parsed, when I remove created MySQL rows to try again I notice something weird, I have only 5 rows I need to leave untouched so I delete every row with **id > 5**, after running this query I noticed that MySQL added the left rows from PHP previous request.
My problem is that all this code works for packages with less than 10 apps with no dlcs, but this one has 9 apps, one of them has 45 dlcs, so it stops working.

Sorry for my English, if you don't understand what I wrote or need more info, let me know before downvoting.
Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I check the code, and the page loads, bu then stops, the MySQL query keeps running until it completes. I don't have any idea why the page loading breaks...

Comment: Please reduce your code of the minimum needed. I'm sure, you wouldn't encounter an error, if you would use a prepared statement with placeholders to bind your input values to. This isn't valid only for your insert but for the other operations too. MySQLi supports prepared statements. Use them.

Comment: @VMai the problem is that this code works, for smaller apps lists, but not for one large as this one. The syntax is correct it's a process problem.

Comment: I still think moving to prepared statements would be a good idea. You won't regret it. But for the debugging of this I would recommend you to log your queries before you execute them. Then you have a chance to see the problem. Maybe you could have a look at the MySQL query log too, if you can enable the global logging.

Comment: @VMai Ok, I'll try to log MySQL queries

Comment: @VMai Ok, here's what's going on then. PHP starts loading and does everything, page interrupts loading, but MySQL continue INSERT process even after page is not loading anymore. Now, do you know why the page stops loading?

Comment: The script you're showing doesn't output anything. So it's waiting for MySQL completing it's work. You should have a look at the slow query log of MySQL which query is so slow. And if it's for debugging purposes, you could do some output, so you see, it's still working. It must be enough that you don't get a problem with buffering (1024 Bytes iirc).

Comment: @VMai Yes, it does not output anything. It waits for MySQL to finish and then redirect the user to another page (which depends from the queries).

Comment: If it doesn't output anything and you want to use header redirection then there's nothing you can do but wait.

Comment: @VMai Ok, but the page interrupts loading, what can I do to avoid that?

Comment: The web application I'm using at work (as user) will sometimes load two or three minutes, if I'm getting too much info. You could check the live headers your browser get. There must be a time out or some such. But one possibility could be the slow queries. Have a look at them and check if you can improve their performance.